# Crystal Report - SQL command vs linking through 'Database Expert Links'

Tags: crystal-reports

I just wonder if there is a way to move the criteria from WHERE clause to FROM using the linking throught 'Database Expert' Links?

thanks
TT

[image: LinkVsSQLcommand]

Comment: I can clearly see tables you used in database expert are different that that you used in sql query? that is the reason you are not able to see the data

Comment: No it's the same tables, I might have typed in incorrectly but it's same tables....do you know a way to fix this by using database expert?

Comment: are joins same in both database expert and your query?

Comment: Yes joins are same, difference in where clause...my question is not so much why they are different it's more of like is there a way to modify the query done by database expert, so far I can't seem to find a way to modify...if you know MS Access, you use the wizard to do the heavy lifting then slightly modify the SQL to waht exactly you are looking for...thanks Siva

Comment: There is no way that you can modify the query generated by crystal reports..

Comment: Actually query you wrote is weird..atleast I havent seen this type of decleration....how it is posible to specify a condition wihtout where clause

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, so SQL command is the only way to go..thanks for spending time with my question, much appreciated

Comment: No problem you are welcome...any way id ok final goal is to get correct data and correct report

Comment: As for the weird part, I know what you mean, I personally put all conditions in where clause but in this case the result will be wrong if you do that, so that why you have to put that where in the join...the problem with Crystal expert is they pull all conditions in where clause, and in this case it's not correct